# Valgrind report write error? why?

Tags: c++, valgrind

When running Valgrind's memcheck, occasionally valgrind report error like this:

```
==2745== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2745== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2745== Using Valgrind-3.6.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2745== Command: ./HSFramework
==2745== 
==2745== Invalid write of size 8
==2745==    at 0x3B81C097C0: do_lookup_x (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
==2745==    by 0x1C31032D: ???
==2745==    by 0x3B81C09E19: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
==2745==  Address 0x7feffee78 is on thread 1's stack
==2745== 

platform: Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is not clue about my code from this error report. 
I had no idea about this error report.
What reasons will lead to this error?

Comment: could you show us your code

Comment: There is no clue about your code? How much can you pair the code down and still produce this error, and with what frequency? valgrind doesn't generally report errors on a whim, Usually there is a reason for it.

Comment: I had found the clue about my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you are getting a buffer overrun in do_lookup_x, if you got its source look at that or share with us.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Comment: There is a error which alloc much more memory in the stack, lead to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `do_lookup_x` function has performed an invalid write access.  That function is part of the [runtime library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768919/what-is-dl-lookup-symbol-x-c-profiling) (and not likely the origin of the issue). I would contact the author of HSFramework to see if they can fix this issue by running valgrind as you did

Comment: I had fixed this issue. I alloc memory which's size is large in the heap instead of stack.